# Is it smart to use asp.net Application[] for caching website contents?

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to do a project with asp.net and i want to know is it true too use Application for caching the contents of website?

for example I used a method with 100 line code and the method connected to database and did a lot of things... and finally it returns a string which length of it is 10000 chars.. is it true to save this string in asp.net application and use this application till the program is working instead of do the method every time? or i have to do this method every time when users check my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should probably use the word 'smart' instead of 'true'.
2. You can do what you write. You can also simply use static classes to store your "cache". In my opinion it is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: Hah, replacing smart with true and the question almost makes sense. Incredible. :D

Comment: thx for your answer :X i decide to use static classes for cache

Comment: +1 for true to smart conversion